# Installed webite on hosting but Can't see my theme styles opencart

Tags: php, layout, opencart

installed on the hosting but does not see the theme styles, skips the theme name like this:

```
/catalog/view/theme//stylesheet/stylesheet.css
```

googled but nothing came up, who came across

Comment: Topic title @MaZzimo24 should be

Comment: /catalog/view/theme//stylesheet/stylesheet.css (Double slash // )! I think here is the "STYLE" folder missing. Maybe there is inside a empty PHP string. 
Without knowing your system, I'll just guess. Check your database table with the settings where the value with the current design may be stored, there will certainly not have been a value entered after installation. Enter an available design manually.

Answer (score 1):

There must be your theme name. By default:

```
 /catalog/view/theme/default/stylesheet/stylesheet.css
```

If you have installed some new theme should be:

```
/catalog/view/theme/your_theme_name/stylesheet/stylesheet.css
```

Comment: yes, but opencart don't see default word and theme name.

Comment: @Tester, check your Database Table

Comment: @MaZzIMo24 delete my project and I installed hosting new project, good install